# android native backspace is not working on a input field which uses custom directives for validation

Tags: android, angularjs, angularjs-directive, android-4.4-kitkat

android native backspace button is not working while using angular and phone gap.

I've used directives and validations. 
 Below is my code.

It is working fine in ios and browser.
please respond as soon as possible.

note1:validations are working fine but that backspace button is not triggered when i am typing values and tap on backspace on android device moto g(4.4) ,when i tap on that input and taps backspaces it will remove  one char or two..again the same process is to be repeated to remove all the test..

note2:same directive is used for password validation too ,here i don't have any problem with backspace on any device

```
test1=angular.module('myTest',[]);
test1.directive('isAmount', function() {

return {
    restrict : 'A',
    require : '?ngModel',

    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        scope.flag = 0;
        scope.count = 0;

        if(!ngModel)
            return;
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(inputValue) {

            scope.flag = 0;
            scope.count = 0;
            var digits = inputValue.split('').filter(function(s) {
                if(attrs.isAmount == "withTwoDigits") {
                    if(scope.flag == 0) {
                        if(s == '.') {
                            scope.flag = 1;
                            return true;
                        } else
                            return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' ');
                    } else {
                        if(s == '.') {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if(scope.count < 2) {
                                if(!isNaN(s) == true)
                                    scope.count++;
                                return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' ');
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else if(attrs.isAmount == "justamount") {
                    if(s == '.') {
                        return false;
                    } else
                        return (!isNaN(s) && s != ' ');
                }
            }).join('');
            ngModel.$viewValue = digits;
            ngModel.$render();
            element.focus = true;
            return digits;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

This is my directive used for validation for an input in my view(HTML)

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enterQuantity" name="userId" ng-model="gp.userId"  ng-maxlength="30" ng-required="true" id="userId" my-maxlength =30 is-amount="withTwoDigits"  ng-trim="false" clear-icon/>
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="passwd" ng-blur="blurField(2)" ng-focus="focusField(2)" ng-model="passwd" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="12" ng-required="true" id="passwd" my-maxlength=12 is-amount="justamount" clear-icon/>
```

Comment: Which version of angular you are using?.  Please post it in angular and android forums in other sites also which may help you.

Comment: I did some tests here, the problem is that the "text composition" feature does not fire the keyboard event in the same way. The angular had this problem before: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5464

If you turn it off it will works again... I'm trying to figure out a better solution...